# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: cannot locate symbol from a dependent shared library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I saw some crash reports from few devices (all arm64 acrhitecture) that looked like that:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNK6TagLib4File10propertiesEv" referenced by "/data/app/com.app.my/lib/arm64/libtaglib-wrapper.so"...
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
       at helpers.TagReaderService.(SourceFile)
```

The OS version affected is 5.1. Since I read that the same problem (but related to system dependencies) happens because of wrong `APP_PLATFORM`, I double checked that it was right and in fact I'm targeting `android-16`.

I should mention that the symbol is declared in another shared library `taglib.so` which is then linked to the second one `taglib-wrapper.so`.

I also performed an `objdump` of both
taglib.so:

```
0000000000140590 g    DF .text  000000000000004c  Base        TagLib::File::properties() const
```

and taglib-wrapper.so:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              TagLib::File::properties() const
```

So the symbol get correctly propagated to the `taglib-wrapper.so` library.
Personally I'm using a arm64 device and have no issue.
I also checked that the `Application.mk` was not being ignored adding random chars to it and performing a Gradle build. No relevant NDK-config code inside gradle.build file.

You can file the `cpp` code on the [Git repo](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/taglib2/taglib/toolkit/tfile.h).

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a x86 armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti -fexceptions
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# ======= TagLib engine ============================

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := taglib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ape \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/asf \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/dsf \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ebml \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ebml/matroska \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/flac \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/it \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mod \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mp4 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpc \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v1 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v2 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v2/frames \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/flac \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/opus \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/speex \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/vorbis \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff/aiff \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff/wav \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/s3m \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/toolkit \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/trueaudio \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/wavpack \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/xm
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/**/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/**/**/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/**/**/**/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# ======= TagLib wrapper ===========================

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := taglib-wrapper
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ape \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/asf \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/dsf \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ebml \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ebml/matroska \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/flac \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/it \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mod \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mp4 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpc \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v1 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v2 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/mpeg/id3v2/frames \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/flac \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/opus \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/speex \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/ogg/vorbis \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff/aiff \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/riff/wav \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/s3m \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/toolkit \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/trueaudio \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/wavpack \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/taglib/xm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := taglib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := taglib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**UPDATE:**
I merged the two library inside an unique shared library. Now that same device (Meizu MX4) crashes at the first JNI call of that library:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void helpers.IOWrapper.initialize() (tried Java_helpers_IOWrapper_initialize and Java_helpers_IOWrapper_initialize__) at helpers.IOWrapper.initialize(Native Method) at helpers.IOWrapper.read(SourceFile:136) at helpers.IOWrapper.read(SourceFile:123) at helpers.TagReaderService$a.run(SourceFile:58) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How is possible that it's the only device crashing? I'm loading the library thought static declaration is the same Java class. I'm using extern C declaration to wrap the cpp file. Maybe it's because I'm missing JNIEXPORT and JNICALL?

Comment: This may have changed in more recent versions of Android but that said - shared libraries loaded from Java so __not__ cascade load any other shared libraries.  You need to explicitly load the most dependent library 1st then the next etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten i did not specified it, but I correctly loaded them in the right order with loadLibrary()

Comment: @RichardCritten you are right in general, but this was fixed in android-21, so no arm64 device needs explicit load of dependencies.

Comment: A cursory search for [Meizu MX4 UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=Meizu+MX4+UnsatisfiedLinkError) revelas that this device does display weird behavior. We have found that some ROMs fail to unpack the native libs correctly from APK to `/data/app/com.app.my/lib/…`. This happens more often on upgrade, but also on clean install. To verify if this is the issue, you should simply capture `ls -l /data/app/com.app.my/lib/*` on the problematic device. You don't need root: the directory should be world-readable.

Comment: @AlexCohn I did the same search before but most of the issues where on chinese repos so I wasn't quite sure. I will try to reach the user asking if he wants to help with adb command

Comment: You can run the `ls` command from your Java code via `Runtime.exec()`, and send the output to logcat, or to file. No need to bother a distant user with adb.

Comment: @AlexCohn if you elaborate a short reply, I can mark it as the answer of the question

Comment: How did you fix the *crash at the first JNI call*?

Comment: @AlexCohn no fix, no matter how I changed nor merged the shared modules, it was still crash at the first at the first call the ap made to the JNI library. This was only a problem with Meizu MX4 and another model I can't remember. Not a problem in the code itself, so I just gave up.

Comment: so, my reply cannot qualify as answer, can it?

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47423096/192373 and discussion around it.