# Native crash (UnsatisfiedLinkError) when the application is updated

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an app that uses some native code. The applications works fine and contains all the abis but in some android devices like Galaxy Note5 with Android 7.0 and SM-G955U (Samsung Galaxy S8 plus) with Android 7.0 the application crashes with the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found
```

These are the abis included in the APK:

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
mips
mips64
x86
x86_64
```

Anybody knows how can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the processor architecture supported for these two devices ??

Comment: Those devices are using ARM64. The weird thing is that not all the S8 plus devices are crashing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem related to some Android versions and also to the package manager.

The solution for me was to use the [ReLinker](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker) library. The following article gives a good description to this issue and how to solve it:

https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/the-perils-of-loading-native-libraries-on-android-befa49dce2db

Answer (score 0):

If your problem only exists on devices with API >= 23, you can set [application/extractNativeLibs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#extractNativeLibs) to **false** in your Manifest, and the native libraries will be used without unpacking. This can also reduce disk requirements for your app.